# Получение объекта типа Ole

Tags: c#, ole

Доброго времени. В меня возникла проблема с получением объекта ole из БД. В меня есть таблица Tovar и у нее есть поле Image - тип OLE, для товара загружена картинка. На форме в combobox я выбираю товар и по нажатию на кнопочку в picturebox появляется картинка для соответствующего товара,
вот код при нажатии кнопки

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Data.QueryWithImage(pictureBox1, "select Image from Tovar where Name = '" + combo_name_tovar.Text + "'"); // Эта строка подсвечивается
}
```

А вот и сам метод QueryWithImage

```
static public void QueryWithImage(PictureBox picturebox, string query)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source" + Data.conn_string;
    OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader oledbReader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (oledbReader.HasRows)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        foreach (DbDataRecord record in oledbReader)
        {
            memoryStream.Write((byte[])record["Image"], 0, ((byte[])record["Image"]).Length);
        }
        Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream); // **Здесь исключение "Недопустимый параметр"** (рис.2)
        picturebox.Image = image;
        memoryStream.Dispose();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Запрос вернул ноль строк");
    conn.Close();
}
```

Exception "Недопустимый параметр":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подсвеченная строка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что у вас в этот момент находится в memoryStream, случайно не null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access дописывает в OLE-поле заголовок, который нужно вырезать перед загрузкой картинки. Вот хелпер для вырезания заголовка:

```
class OleHelper
{
    public static byte[] GetImageBytesFromOLEField(byte[] oleFieldBytes)
    {
        const string BITMAP_ID_BLOCK = "BM";
        const string JPG_ID_BLOCK = "\u00FF\u00D8\u00FF";
        const string PNG_ID_BLOCK = "\u0089PNG\r\n\u001a\n";
        const string GIF_ID_BLOCK = "GIF8";
        const string TIFF_ID_BLOCK = "II*\u0000";

        byte[] imageBytes;

        // Get a UTF7 Encoded string version
        Encoding u8 = Encoding.UTF7;
        string strTemp = u8.GetString(oleFieldBytes);

        // Get the first 300 characters from the string
        string strVTemp = strTemp.Substring(0, 300);

        // Search for the block
        int iPos = -1;
        if (strVTemp.IndexOf(BITMAP_ID_BLOCK) != -1)
            iPos = strVTemp.IndexOf(BITMAP_ID_BLOCK);
        else if (strVTemp.IndexOf(JPG_ID_BLOCK) != -1)
            iPos = strVTemp.IndexOf(JPG_ID_BLOCK);
        else if (strVTemp.IndexOf(PNG_ID_BLOCK) != -1)
            iPos = strVTemp.IndexOf(PNG_ID_BLOCK);
        else if (strVTemp.IndexOf(GIF_ID_BLOCK) != -1)
            iPos = strVTemp.IndexOf(GIF_ID_BLOCK);
        else if (strVTemp.IndexOf(TIFF_ID_BLOCK) != -1)
            iPos = strVTemp.IndexOf(TIFF_ID_BLOCK);
        else
            throw new Exception("Unable to determine header size for the OLE Object");

        // From the position above get the new image
        if (iPos == -1)
            throw new Exception("Unable to determine header size for the OLE Object");

        imageBytes = new byte[oleFieldBytes.LongLength - iPos];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(oleFieldBytes, iPos, oleFieldBytes.Length - iPos);
        imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        ms.Dispose();
        return imageBytes;
    }
}
```

взят с из [блога Pranab Paul](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pranab/removing-ole-header-from-images-stored-in-ms-access-db-as-ole-object), наиболее общий вариант из тех, что нашлись.

Использовать примерно так (я чуть сократил код):

```
if (oledbReader.HasRows)
{
    var oleBytes = (byte[])oledbReader.Cast<DbDataRecord>().First()["Image"];
    var bitmapBytes = OleHelper.GetImageBytesFromOLEField(oleBytes);
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bitmapBytes))
    {
        picturebox.Image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream); 
    }
}
```

Хоть и костыль, но это официальный костыль, для него даже есть [отдельная статья в MS Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175261), но в ней код только на VB (не VB.NET).

Comment: спасибо огромное